# Where to remove domain from username? ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-authentication

This is an intranet application written in MVC 4 which requires user login. Where is the best place to remove the domain from the username entered by the user? (`Username.Name.Split('\')[1];`). This is incase the user enters the domain.

**View:**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed.")
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div style="width: 400px">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)
            </div>
            ...
```

**Login Model:**

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Username")]
public string Username { get; set; }
....
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                //set authentication cookie
                ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the username and not the domain why not validate as early as possible, e.g. don't all \ in username.   As always have server validation to back this up in Login action like you suggest, e.g.

```
if(model.UserName.Contains('\')  
         model.UserName = model.Username.Name.Split('\')[1];
```

If it is always the same domain, put the domain name beside the text box to make it clear it is not being asked for.

Comment: I would like to validate as early as possible. How do I do this in the view? Is it necessary to also perform this check in the Login action? I like your suggestion of putting the domain name next to the text box.

Comment: have you client validation working with your DataAnnotations?

Comment: I don't have any client validation. Should I use jquery? I haven't done this before.

Comment: there are a few options there.  one worth reading is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(VS.100).aspx

Comment: you would add regex DataAnnotation to your UserName to say what is allowed, then the unobstrusive client validation should do the rest once hooked in and you have a display message added.